# Подскажите какой-нибудь готовый слайдер, где слайды друг на друге

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, slider

Нужно реализовать вот такой слайдер как на фото (слайды должны уходить в бок и появляться внизу всех карточек. Slick слайдер не подходит и Swiper Slider тоже не подходит:( Искал в интернете, ничего больше нормального найти не смог[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

swiper.js там как раз недавно добавили такой слайдер
вот сама ссылка на такой слайдер [посмотреть](https://swiperjs.com/demos#effect-cards)